# How to run a loop using gui object names in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a gui form, where multiple text boxes are present. I want to put their values inside an array.  One way of doing it is by writing something like this

```
{array element } = ui->text_1->text();
```

and repeat it for text_2,text_3 upto n.

What I want is to run a loop and replace number portion of text box name in each cycle.

something like this   `{array element } = ui->text_{This number getting changed }->text();`

How can it be done in qt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option to those listed would be to create an array using an initializer list.  Depending on how big the array is (and how often it changes), this might be workable.

```
QLineEdit* entries[] = { ui->text_0, ui->text_1, ui=>text_2 };
QStringList answers;
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
{
    answers += entries[i]->text();
}
```

Comment: with this method, you still have to mention the name of each textbox. Matyas's second suggestion is far more quick and IMHO is elegant.

Comment: Matyas' second suggestion is great if either you can know for sure what the order of the text elements is, or you don't care.  If you need to have the elements ordered in some particular manner, this is the simplest way I have come up with so far.

Comment: This is good too if your ui is being generated with a .ui file since those ones have to be named.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. When you create the UI, instead of using `text1`, `text2`, etc. you create an array of `QLineEdit`s (eg. `std::vector<QLineEdit>`) and then when you want to retrieve their values then simply iterate over this array
2. Iterate over the children of the container widget. You can get the list of the children using the following ([documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#children)):

```
   QList<QObject *> list = parentWidget->children();
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an expanded version of Matyas' solution:

```
class MyClass : public QWidget
{
   QStringList answers;
   void FillAnswersList(QObject *base)
   {
       QLineEdit *lineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit>(base);
       if(lineEdit)answers.append(lineEdit->text());       
       else 
       {
           foreach(QObject *child, base->children())
              FillAnswersList(child);
       }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the number changing, and always incrementing, there is another possible solution using `QObject::findChild`, which takes a name as a parameter.

```
QString name_template("text_%1");
QStringList answers;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_TEXTS; ++i)
{
    QLineEdit *edit = ui->findChild<QLineEdit *>(name_template.arg(i));
    answers += edit->text();
}
```